# Localization isn't working for all URL in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-5.8, laravel-localization

I have applied Localization in my Laravel project. But Localization is getting error for some URL.

I have two languages buttons `en` and `bn` in my head section. while user click any of the language button, the whole site will be converted into that language.

**button**

```
<li><a href="{{ 'locale/en' }}">English</a></li>
<li><a href="{{ 'locale/bn' }}">Bangla</a></li>
```

**.env**

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:Dm34MLg8AbQk4ADyIG9cYPaIwYbQgrUgrN7Ani/x+JA=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost:90/office/sencare/
```

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/doctor', 'homeController@doctor'); //route A
Route::get('/doctor/{data}', 'homeController@doctor_detail'); //route B
Route::get('/technology', 'homeController@technology');//route A
Route::get('/technology/{data}', 'homeController@technology_detail'); //route B

Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function () {
    Voyager::routes();
});

// ================LOCALIZATION=============
Route::get('locale/{locale}',function ($locale){
    Session::put('locale',$locale);
    return redirect()->back();
});
// ================LOCALIZATION=============

/*=============START CUSTOMIZE ERROR PAGE===========*/
Route::any('{catchall}', function() {  
  return App::call('App\Http\Controllers\errorController@error');

})->where('catchall', '.*');
/*=============END CUSTOMIZE ERROR PAGE===========*/
```

**Localization Middlewer**

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(\Session::get('locale')){

            \App::setLocale(\Session::get('locale'));

        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

So while user visit pages under `A` type routes and click on any language button to convert the page, it's working fine and converted.

But while user visit pages under `B` type routes and click on any language button to convert the page, then got an error page under customize error routes.

**error message**

> PAGE NOT FOUND
>   The requested URL is not correct.

Another point is that while I clicked upon language button under `A` type route page the url remaining same. But for `B` type route page after clicking the language button the url changed. 
example :

> http://localhost:90/Office/sencare/doctor/locale/en

this `locale/en/` isn't come for any other URL.

How to solve this ?

Anybody help please ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add the error returned from B type routes to your question. Not sure if it matters but your routes shouldn't start with a forward slash. `doctor` not `/doctor`.

Comment: @Jeemusu...I have updated my  post. Please check.

Comment: The buttons your clicking, what are the href="" value? Sounds like your not using an absolute path so the url is being appended to the current url. They should be `href="/locale/en/"`.

Comment: I have updated my post with html button.

Answer (score 0):

From the HTML code you posted I can see that your language buttons are using a relative url path. This means the path does not begin with a forward slash.

Relative paths append the url to the current pages url. For example, if a user on the 
`http://localhost:90/Office/sencare/doctor/` page clicks the Bangla link, they will be taken to `http://localhost:90/Office/sencare/doctor/locale/bn`.

Instead of using a relative path for your url's you should change them to be absolute paths by adding a forward slash to the front of them.

```
<li><a href="{{ '/locale/en' }}">English</a></li>
<li><a href="{{ '/locale/bn' }}">Bangla</a></li>
```

Comment: @Jeemusu.....if I am using forward slash into mu url's `{{ '/locale/en' }}` it gives another error `Object not found`....is it issue with the `.env` file ?....I have updated my post with `.env ` file. Please have a look

Comment: The new error should tell you what line of what file the error is occurring?

Comment: @Jeemusu....there is no error reporting file in `storage/logs`. Whenever I used forward slash in the url's then getting error `Object not found.The requested URL was not found on this server`.....

Comment: It seems like your routes and URL's don't match up.. what is the base URL for your site? If it's `http://localhost:90/Office/sencare/`. Then you need to change your routes to reflect the `/Office/sencare` part of the URL.

Comment: @Jeemusu...Your suggestion doesn't solve the issue brother ... :(